# Grouping PostgreSQL table rows

Tags: postgresql

I would like to group my PostgreSQL table results like this: [ungrouped and grouped results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EFGyK.png).

Ungrouped results:

```
id  time_1                      time_2                      val
1   2024-02-10 07:37:05.946     null                        foo
2   2024-02-10 07:37:05.944     null                        bar
3   2024-02-10 07:37:05.943     null                        bar
4   2024-02-10 07:37:05.942     2024-02-10 07:37:06.942     foo
5   2024-02-10 07:37:05.940     null                        bar
6   2024-02-10 07:37:05.938     null                        bar
7   2024-02-10 07:37:05.937     2024-02-10 07:37:06.937     bar
8   2024-02-10 07:37:05.935     null                        foo
9   2024-02-10 07:37:05.933     null                        foo
```

should be grouped like this:

```
id  time_1                      time_2                      val
3   2024-02-10 07:37:05.943     null                        foo
6   2024-02-10 07:37:05.938     2024-02-10 07:37:06.942     foo
9   2024-02-10 07:37:05.933     2024-02-10 07:37:06.937     bar
```

I've come quite close with LEAD/LAG/ROW_NUMBER window function combinations, but I don't like the amount of CASE's and WHEN's that I had to use to get the wanted results. I would like to know if I could use GROUPing or some other more performance efficient way to get the wanter results?

This is what I've come up so far:

```
WITH numbered_rows AS (
    SELECT
      *,
      FIRST_VALUE(id) OVER (ORDER BY time_1)      AS first_id,
      FIRST_VALUE(time_1) OVER (ORDER BY time_1)  AS first_time_1,
      FIRST_VALUE(time_2) OVER (ORDER BY time_2)  AS first_time_2,
      FIRST_VALUE(val) OVER (ORDER BY time_2)     AS first_val,
      LEAD(id) OVER (ORDER BY time_1)             AS start_id,
      LEAD(time_1) OVER (ORDER BY time_1)         AS start_time,    
      LEAD(time_2) OVER (ORDER BY time_2)         AS end_time,
      LAG(time_2) OVER (ORDER BY time_2)          AS last_end_time,
      LEAD(val) OVER (ORDER BY time_2)            AS end_val,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY time_1) = 1     AS is_first_row
      FROM foo_table
      WHERE bar_id = 'bar'
),
grouped_rows AS (
  SELECT        
    CASE
      WHEN is_first_row THEN first_id
      ELSE start_id
    END AS id,
    CASE
      WHEN is_first_row THEN first_time_1
      WHEN end_time IS NOT null OR last_end_time IS NOT NULL THEN start_time
      ELSE time_1
    END AS time_1,
    CASE
      WHEN is_first_row THEN first_time_2
      ELSE time_2
    END AS time_2,
    CASE
      WHEN is_first_row THEN first_val
      ELSE end_val
    END AS val
  FROM numbered_rows
  WHERE time_2 IS NOT NULL OR is_first_row
)
SELECT * -- I need to do some calculation here. That's why this last select.
FROM grouped_rows
ORDER BY time_1 DESC;
```

Only real problem with this is that last **val** does not get picked from correct row, which should be the last row.

**Explain analyze** gives me results:

```
Sort  (cost=49225.26..49333.77 rows=43404 width=36) (actual time=596.558..604.257 rows=43442 loops=1)
   Sort Key: (CASE WHEN numbered_rows.is_first_row THEN numbered_rows.first_time_1 WHEN ((numbered_rows.end_time IS NOT NULL) OR (numbered_rows.last_end_time IS NOT NULL)) THEN numbered_rows.start_time ELSE n
umbered_rows.time_1 END) DESC
   Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 1960kB
   ->  Subquery Scan on numbered_rows  (cost=44142.27..45881.95 rows=43404 width=36) (actual time=215.332..568.413 rows=43442 loops=1)
         Filter: ((numbered_rows.time_2 IS NOT NULL) OR numbered_rows.is_first_row)
         Rows Removed by Filter: 192
         ->  WindowAgg  (cost=44142.27..45447.03 rows=43492 width=553) (actual time=215.329..554.338 rows=43634 loops=1)
               ->  Sort  (cost=44142.27..44251.00 rows=43492 width=68) (actual time=215.309..224.248 rows=43634 loops=1)
                     Sort Key: foo_table.time_1
                     Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 3680kB
                     ->  WindowAgg  (cost=39595.52..40791.55 rows=43492 width=68) (actual time=100.630..178.918 rows=43634 loops=1)
                           ->  Sort  (cost=39595.52..39704.25 rows=43492 width=36) (actual time=100.616..108.420 rows=43634 loops=1)
                                 Sort Key: foo_table.time_2
                                 Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 1968kB
                                 ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on foo_table  (cost=1405.06..36244.79 rows=43492 width=36) (actual time=10.538..76.810 rows=43634 loops=1)
                                       Recheck Cond: (bar_id = '0d741730-cee9-4745-a4c8-5050b79c869b'::uuid)
                                       Heap Blocks: exact=16481
                                       ->  Bitmap Index Scan on foo_table_bar_id_idx  (cost=0.00..1394.19 rows=43492 width=0) (actual time=5.018..5.018 rows=43685 loops=1)
                                             Index Cond: (bar_id = '0d741730-cee9-4745-a4c8-5050b79c869b'::uuid)
 Planning Time: 0.290 ms
 Execution Time: 611.420 ms
```

I would like the execution time to be better.

Table indexes:

```
 Indexes:
    "foo_table_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "foo_table_bar_id_idx" hash (bar_id)
    "foo_table_time_1_time_2_idx" btree (time_1, time_2)
```

Comment: Please read: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors), [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and, of course, welcome to Stackoverflow!

Comment: Can you explain the logic as of how you would like to group your fields?

Comment: Please post the query you've come up with that gets the wanted results. Without anything to work with, we will not be able to show you how to simplify it.

Comment: `Explain analyze` does give more results than just planning and execution time. Please share the other info too, together with DDL info of the tables used, so we know which indexes exist and which do not exist.

Comment: As you can see in the explain , the index `foo_table_time_1_time_2_idx` is not used, you should investigate some time in defining a better index, which will be used.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Luuk. Might be something to do with my find and replace :), but I will investigate.

Comment: When posting example data, please do so using executable SQL to minimize the effort required to create a demonstration environment. Because your query is processing the entire table instead of filtering for selected rows, it is likely that it won't use any indexes.

Comment: `is_first_row` is always FALSE (see: dbfiddle.uk/sVoKcJBI) That would make the SQL simpler because, at least, 4 field are no longer needed.

Answer (score 0):

Because the grouping rules were not provided, I've attempted to infer them from the example data and expected output; unfortunately, because `val` is not unique, the example is ambiguous. The following query demonstrates one approach to grouping using non-NULL `time_2` as a group boundary marker. Group members include rows with a `time_1` value less than the group boundary's `time_1` value that are not included in a prior group. For each group, `val` comes from the group row with a non-NULL `time_2`. If a group doesn't have such a row, then `val` comes from the row in the group with the greatest `time_1`. Ordering is based on both `time_1` and `id` to ensure determistic results in case `time_1` is not unique.

```
WITH t(id, time_1, time_2, val) AS (
  VALUES (1, '2024-02-10 07:37:05.946'::timestamp, NULL, 'foo'),
         (2, '2024-02-10 07:37:05.944'::timestamp, NULL, 'bar'),
         (3, '2024-02-10 07:37:05.943'::timestamp, NULL, 'bar'),
         (4, '2024-02-10 07:37:05.942'::timestamp, '2024-02-10 07:37:06.942'::timestamp, 'foo'),
         (5, '2024-02-10 07:37:05.940'::timestamp, NULL, 'bar'),
         (6, '2024-02-10 07:37:05.938'::timestamp, NULL, 'bar'),
         (7, '2024-02-10 07:37:05.937'::timestamp, '2024-02-10 07:37:06.937'::timestamp, 'bar'),
         (8, '2024-02-10 07:37:05.935'::timestamp, NULL, 'foo'),
         (9, '2024-02-10 07:37:05.933'::timestamp, NULL, 'foo')),
  groups AS (
    SELECT t.id, t.time_1, t.time_2, t.val,
           COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN t.time_2 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END)
                    OVER (ORDER BY t.time_1, t.id ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING),
                    0) AS group_id
      FROM t)
SELECT (ARRAY_AGG(g.id ORDER BY g.time_1, g.id DESC))[1] AS id,
       MIN(g.time_1) AS time_1,
       MAX(g.time_2) AS time2,
       (ARRAY_AGG(g.val ORDER BY g.time_2 DESC, g.id))[1] AS val
  FROM groups g
  GROUP BY g.group_id
  ORDER BY g.group_id DESC;
```

Comment: I've run a few experiments with and without various permutations of indexes on `time_1`, `time_2`, and `id`. My test table had 525601 rows and the query returned 52376 rows. Even when the indexes were used, there was no statistically significant difference in execution times (~2.2 seconds). This is not unexpected since all rows had to be processed, the columns in the indexes took a significant fraction of the space used in the table, and there was additional I/O required to retrieve the columns that weren't available in the index.

Comment: Thank you so much @JohnH. With the little tweak you solution is perfect.